# Joining these tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have 3 tables as below :

```
Table Name :
------------
UserList            

Column Name
-------------
DealerID        DealerUserID

AAA             111
AAA             222
AAA             333
BBB             111
BBB             444
CCC             111
CCC             555
```

--

```
Table Name :
------------
UserInfo        

Coulmns
--------
DealerUserID    Name    
111             John        
222             James
333             Dany
444             Daniel
555             Romie
```

--

```
Table Name :
------------
CarPermitted    

Coulmns
--------
DealerID        DealerUserID

AAA             111
AAA             222
BBB             111
CCC             111
```

I want a **result** as below of a query which will take input as :

For DealerID = AAA

```
Name    DealerUserID    AllowedStatus

John    111         true
James   222         true
Dany    333         false
```

I have tried many joins as below, but could not get my desired result. Any suggestion how can I get it.

AllowedStatus is the value I need to fetch as :

If the combination of DealerID and DealerUserID from table UserList is present in CarPermitted///rest will be false..

Note : It will display all the dealeruserId belongs to one dealer

Comment: you did not specify which table the column `AllowedStatus` belongs to.

Comment: @James How do you get your allowed status?

Comment: AllowedStatus -- This is what is causing me the problem..I dynamically need to get this value

Comment: @James then you should give us enough information how do you calculate it.

Comment: where did the heck allowedStatus come from, It just sprout from nowhere?

Comment: @James that would really cause you a great problem if you didn`t know were to pulled it off..

Comment: Please see the edit..sorry for the less information

Comment: i see it check my answer this would probably help you anyway,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you don't show your queries so I can say how you were going wrong

From the comments, Allowed status comes from if the record exists in the permitted table.

```
SELECT UF.Name, UF.DealerUserID, 
       CASE P.DealerID IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS AllowedStatus
FROM UserList UL
JOIN UserInfo UF ON UL.DealerUserID = UF.DealerUserID
LEFT JOIN CarPermitted P ON UL.DealerUserID = P.DealerUserID AND UL.DealerID = P.DealerID
WHERE UL.DealerID = 'AAA'
```

Comment: You have an error :) `CASE WHEN P.DealerID IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS AllowedStatus`